# Get Response With Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

i'm trying to receive response with retrofit + rxjava + gson

and our backend developed with laravel.

the problem is gson cant convert json to my java class

here is samples of my classes and responses

sample of response :

```
{
"data": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "name",
    "last_name": "last name",
    "phone_number": "091212345678",
    "avatar": null
}
```

}

and the java class :

```
public class User {
private Long id;
private String name;
private String last_name;
private String phone_number;
private String role;
@SerializedName("avatar")
private String profilePicture;


public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return last_name;
}

public void setLastName(String last_name) {
    this.last_name = last_name;
}

public String getPhone_number() {
    return phone_number;
}

public void setPhone_number(String phone_number) {
    this.phone_number = phone_number;
}

public String getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public String getProfilePicture() {
    return profilePicture;
}

public void setProfilePicture(String profilePicture) {
    this.profilePicture = profilePicture;
}
```

i dont know what "data" in json response is.

and why gson cant convert json to java.

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this json response is nested You should design the class like below by wrapping user object inside to parse this response properly.

```
public class User {

public Long id;
public String name;
public String last_name;
public String phone_number;
public String avatar;

}
-----------------------------------
public class Data {

public User user;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Redesign your Model Class Like this:

```
public class User {

@SerializedName("data")
public Data data;

// Generate getter setter for all the field here

}
```

Now Create another class named **Data** with your Json property:

```
public class Data {

public Long id;
public String name;
public String last_name;
public String phone_number;
public String avatar;

// Generate getter setter for all the field here

}
```

Now you can access the fields like this:

```
User user = new User();
//get name
user.getData().getName();
//set name
user.getData().setName("Demo");
```

Comment: i see you've been recently editing questions on SO, thanks for all the help in doing that :) when making an edit, please also check if the question _really_ needs the android studio tag, it's something a lot of people add for no reason, as an example, this question also had the tag and there's no need for it

Comment: this answer helped me, thank you! 
but i dont understand why laravel puts "data" and extra layer in responses
its not neccessary

Answer (score 0):

You have a JSON object called "data" and the User class does not contain a data field to store the contents of the "data" object. Gson is looking for a field named "data" in the User class that can hold the contents of the "data" object and isn't finding it. Now there are two ways to go about this.

1. Return your JSON object in this format:

   {
   "id": 3,
   "name": "name",
   "last_name": "last name",
   "phone_number": "091212345678",
   "avatar": null
   }

OR

2.1 Create a Data class and declare it in the User class:

```
public class Data {  
private Long id;  
private String name;  
private String last_name;  
private String phone_number;  
private String role;  
@SerializedName("avatar")  
private String profilePicture;  
/*Getters and setters here*/ }
```

2.1. Declare Data field in User class

```
public class User {  private Data data; public Data getData() {  return data; }}
```